# How to solve the else/if problems in password input?

Tags: java, if-statement

I wrote a program that users can login. Below u see some codes that I wrote for the password input but the second `if` of them does not work properly.

Please help me to find the problem. Why it does not work?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Password {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner passwordInput = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Please enter your password: ");
        int builtInPassword = 1254;

        if (passwordInput.hasNextInt() && passwordInput.nextInt() == builtInPassword) {
            System.out.println("Your password is correct.");
        } else if (passwordInput.hasNextInt() && passwordInput.nextInt() != builtInPassword) {
            System.out.println("The password entered is incorrect");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Sorry, please enter the right format");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly "doesn't work"?

Comment: `passwordInput.nextInt()` in your first if statement consumes the input from the Scanner so the else if will never receive anything.

Comment: To expand on Ben's comment: read the password once (`passwordInput.hasNextInt()`) and check it multiple times.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you call nextInt() in all ifs. This way you basically wait for another input each time you call passwordInput.nextInt().

Try to save the user input and then check it for the password. Something like:

```
if (passwordInput.hasNextInt()) {
    int pass = passwordInput.nextInt();
    if (pass == builtInPassword) {
        System.out.println("Your password is correct.");
    } else {
        System.out.println("The password entered is incorrect");
    }
} else {
    System.out.println("Sorry, please enter the right format");
}
```

I am writing without a compiler here so I am not sure it will compile properly but you can get the idea ;)

Comment: That's pretty complete right there ;) We are not free code writing service you know

Answer (score 1):

`scanner.hasNextInt()` check the value is int or not, but its not consume the value. but in your code "pasword not matching" case scanner will go through two ifs and two `hasNextInt()` callings. therefore in second if it will return false value.

you can correct and optimize you code using exceptions as follow.

```
try {
     if(passwordInput.nextInt()==builtInPassword){
         System.out.println("Your password is correct.");
     }else{
         System.out.println("The password entered is incorrect");
     }
 } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
     System.out.println("Sorry, please enter the right format");        
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

As noted by others, the problem is that you are calling `nextInt()` twice, and it tries to get a new int each time. The simplest solution would be to change your first `else` to `else if (passwordInput.hasNextInt()) {`, as you already know the second condition (the password is wrong) holds from the fact that the `if` failed. However, I would advise restructuring your code so that there is no need to call `hasNextInt` twice either, as this seems cleaner:

```
if (passwordInput.hasNextInt()) {
    if (passwordInput.nextInt() == builtInPassword) {
        System.out.println("Your password is correct.");
    } else {
        System.out.println("The password entered is incorrect.");
    }
} else {
    System.out.println("Sorry, please enter the right format");
}
```

Answer (score -2):

I you need a `while` loop.

```
while (passwordInput.nextInt() != builtInPassword) {
   System.out.println("Incorrect password");
}
System.out.println("Correct password!");
```

Comment: `hasNextInt` returns a boolean value. Comparing that to an integer tends to not work out.

Comment: not to mention, this would change the functionality, which is not the goal

Comment: You are right. It should be `nextInt` instead of `hasNextInt`