# Solve if/else problems in getting Scanner input

Tags: java, if-statement

I created two Scanner objects ant got them. but when getting inputs is finished, if/else codes do not work. where is the problem?the main problem is about "InputMismatchException". i wana when user typed a value except a double, program show him "Please enter the right format". i wana handle this exception with this two inputs. what is the right code?can you explain me please and write the right code?tnx.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class NestedIf {

public static void main(String[] args) {


    Scanner iqInput=new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please enter your IQ: ");
    iqInput.nextDouble();


    Scanner termMeanInput=new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please enter your term mean: ");
    termMeanInput.nextDouble();


    if(iqInput.hasNextDouble() && termMeanInput.hasNextDouble()){

        if(iqInput.nextDouble()>110 && termMeanInput.nextDouble()>18){
            System.out.println("You got 30 percent discount.");

        }else if(iqInput.nextDouble()>100 && termMeanInput.nextDouble()>17){
            System.out.println("You got 20 percent discount.");

        }else if(iqInput.nextDouble()<100 && termMeanInput.nextDouble()<17){
            System.out.println("You have no discount");
        }
    }else{
        System.out.println("Please enter the right format");
    }
}

}
```

Comment: `nextDouble()` consumes a double each time it is called

Comment: What's the expected output? What's a sample input? You should use one `Scanner` per source and since you have only one source (System.in) you should consider only one Scanner.

Comment: "codes do not work" -> what does that means ? It didn't compile -> what error do you get ? It crashes -> what exceptions do you get ? The outputs are not the expected ones ? -> what are they ? what were you expecting ? Have you tried to debug it ?     You need to explain this to us if you expect an answer

Comment: "nextDouble" Scanner's method **returns** the input. You need to assign the value to a variable. Here you consume your input and then in the if ask for new input. And moreover, you don't need 2 Scanners, one is clearly enough here.

Comment: On a side note: Someone answered a very similar question of yours quite well [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50598443/how-to-solve-the-else-if-problems-in-password-input). Also you might want to do some research on how a `Scanner` works e.g. by reading the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextDouble()).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem:** Here you are reading values from `iqInput.nextDouble();` and `termMeanInput.nextDouble();`. However You are not storing their values in any variables in order to use it in if statements.

**Try this:**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    try {
        System.out.print("Please enter your IQ: ");
        Double IQ = s.nextDouble(); // Modification 

        System.out.print("Please enter your term mean: ");
        Double termMean = s.nextDouble();

        if(IQ<100 && termMean<17) {
            System.out.println("You have no discount");
        } else if(IQ>110 && termMean>18) {
            System.out.println("You got 30 percent discount.");
        } else {
            System.out.println("You got 20 percent discount.");
        }
    }
    catch(InputMismatchException e) {
        System.out.println("Please enter the right input format.");
    }
}
```

**Modifications:**

1. Added `Double IQ = iqInput.nextDouble(); and  Double termMean = termMeanInput.nextDouble();`.
2. Used values of `IQ and termMean` in if-else statements.

Comment: @vincrichaud you are right, Modified my answer. Thanks.

Comment: thanks for answer. but the main problem is about "InputMismatchException". i wana when user typed a value except a double, program show him "Please enter the right format". i wana handle this exception with this two inputs. what is the right code?

Comment: @NeamatTabani Ok. Just wait and let me modify my answer.

Comment: @NeamatTabani You can now check my modified answer. Here I used the concept of Exception handling. Let me know are u aware of that or not otherwise I will explain you.

Comment: Thank you so much @Nitin Bisht. i can understand the codes.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because you call scanning method in if condition.

Can't you use one scanner and put scanned value into variable?

Answer (score 0):

If we use one scanner instead of 2, and store the inputs,

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class NestedIf {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Double iq, mean;

    Scanner iqInput=new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please enter your IQ: ");
    iq = iqInput.nextDouble();

    System.out.println("Please enter your term mean: ");
    mean = iqInput.nextDouble();


    if(iq != null && mean != null){

        if(iq>110 && mean>18){
            System.out.println("You got 30 percent discount.");

        }else if(iq>100 && mean>17){
            System.out.println("You got 20 percent discount.");

        }else if(iq<100 && mean<17){
            System.out.println("You have no discount");
        }
    }else{
        System.out.println("Please enter the right format");
    }
}

}
```